# Geometry nodes: scale instances based on distance between two planes

Tags: node-editor, geometry, instances

I would like to use Geometry nodes to instance pillars (cylinders or columns with their origin at the bottom) on the lower plane. Then I want to scale these in the Z-direction so that the pillars reach to upper plane, effectively creating a volume (instanced objects as voxels) between the two planes using instanced points. what kind of approach would be best here.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: A very simple non gnodes approach  is distribute with array / duplis, and project top and bottom of cylinder via shrinkwrap modifiers or constraints.  As mentioned here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229793/geometry-nodes-snap-object-to-ground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do that with the raycast node like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

The raycast node is great in finding "hit points" and distances if you give it the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris!! I left out the Point Distribute to create an even, non-random distribution of points. I never knew about the existence of the Raycast node. I had to upgrade to 3.0 alpha. Thanks!

Comment: glad i could help, please tap on the checkmark left to my answer if it helped you. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, could you please update this answer or write another that would work up to date to the current implementation of geometry node ?

Comment: Hi Softyoda, i am sorry, but i you look at my profile - answers you will see - i wrote a LOT of them. And no, i will not update all my answers for all new Blender versions, sorry. If you want an answer for a newer version, please ask a new question. thx.